# Play HTML5 Video on Twitter Bootstrap Modal appearance

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a video still graphic to trigger a Bootstrap modal that has an HTML5 video within. I HAVE TO get the video to begin playing when the modal appears and I don't seem to be able to select it with jQuery.

The trigger image has an ID of btnVideo.

Here's the modal code:

```
<div id="modal-video-view" class="modal hide fade in" style="display:none;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Property Video</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="vid">
            <video width="520" height="380" preload autostart id="myVideo">
                <source src="videos/homeVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="videos/homeVideo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            </video>

            <script>
                jwplayer("myVideo").setup({
                    modes: [
                        { type: "flash", src: "js/jw_player_5.8/player.swf" },
                        { type: "html5" }
                    ]
                });
            </script>
        </div> <!-- END vid DIV -->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my attempt at jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#btnVideo').click( function(){
    $('#modal-video-view').modal();
    $('#myVideo').get(0).play();
      });
});
```

The video is not playing when the modal is "modaled." I don't know but maybe it is because jQuery isn't sure if the m4a or the ogg is loaded or if the flash fallback is in play

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Jon

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in the JW Player documentation.

```
$('#btnVideo').click( function(){
    $('#modal-video-view').modal();
    jwplayer("myVideo").setup({
         modes: [
        { type: "flash", src: "js/jw_player_5.8/player.swf"}, { type: "html5" }
         ]
    });
    jwplayer("myVideo").play();
});
```